# Database Allow Duplicate Entry for Foreign Key in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to allow date duplicate entry for foreign keys. Is there any method in Django I can do it? your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you. Eg: I have a user "X" and "Y" and I want to store work status such as (my work entry time, my work exit time) but on the same date it can done only once by both the user.

## models.py

```
class TimesheetDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="timesheet",null="True")
    date = models.DateField(max_length = 10,unique=True)
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    startTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    endTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    breakTime = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    normalTime = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    overTime = models.FloatField(max_length = 10)
    holidayTime = models.FloatField(max_length = 10)
    weekType = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    attendance = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    content = models.TextField( max_length = 300)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

**models.py**

```
class TimesheetDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="timesheet",null="True")
    date = models.DateField()
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    startTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    endTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    breakTime = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    normalTime = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    overTime = models.FloatField(max_length = 10)
    holidayTime = models.FloatField(max_length = 10)
    weekType = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    attendance = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    content = models.TextField( max_length = 300)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'date')
```

Comment: Thank you :D I
 guess it worked but do you mind if I ask for an explanation.

Comment: please have a look [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding "unique_together" in your TimesheetDetails model's Meta class and removing the "unqiue" constraint from date field...

```
class TimesheetDetails(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user','date'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="timesheet",null="True")
    date = models.DateField(max_length = 10)
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    startTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    endTime = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    breakTime = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    normalTime = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    overTime = models.FloatField(max_length = 10)
    holidayTime = models.FloatField(max_length = 10)
    weekType = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    attendance = models.CharField( max_length = 10)
    content = models.TextField( max_length = 300)
```